# Short circuit evaluation in ruby / rails with defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, short-circuiting

Looking to have two tests on a variable, that might not be defined in a rails view.

```
<% if defined(:var) && var.present? %>
    <%= var.value %>
<% end %>
```

However, this is throwing a `undefined local variable or method` error when `var` is not defined. I assumed ruby/rails would short circuit the first expression and not try to evaluate the second, similar to python

```
>>> a = False
>>> a and b
False
>>> b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Any reason why short circuit is preceeding to the second evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
if defined?(var) && var.present?
```

`:var` will always be defined as it's a symbol.

```
> defined?(:var)
=> "expression"
> defined?(var)
=> nil
> var = 1
=> 1
> defined?(var)
=> "local-variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

`defined?` expect you to pass the expression, not a `Symbol`. The `Symbol` will always return true.

```
2.1.5 :001 > defined? var
 => nil
2.1.5 :002 > defined? :var
 => "expression"
2.1.5 :003 > var = nil
 => nil
2.1.5 :004 > defined? var
 => "local-variable"
```

Hence

```
<% if defined?(var) && var.present? %>
  <%= var.value %>
<% end %>
```